# Any suggestions on how I can change a whole line using regular expressions find and replace in notepad ++?

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML document that has end times in there, I need to change the format from this

```
end="00:00:09:02">
```

to this

```
end="00:09.02">
```

so basically the first two numbers and colon deleted, and the last colon replaced by a period.

I have hundreds to change, and was trying to figure out how to do edit them all using a script of some sort, does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the original line:

```
    <p start="00:00:13:23" EndTimecode="00:00:17:02" Title='Let’s start with RIM and
the High Velocity Sector.'/>
```

Here is what I need to end up with:

```
    <p begin="00:13.23" end="00:17.02">Let’s start with RIM and
the High Velocity Sector.</p>
```

I have updated my question due to discovering that find and replace is the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be regexp.

Regexp: `/(?:EndTimecode="[0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(?:")/`

Replace String: `end="$1:$2.$3"`

You would use it like so:

1. Read the xml file and store it into a var (call it `$contents`)
2. `$contents = preg_replace('/(?:EndTimecode="[0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(?:")/', 'end="$1:$2.$3"', $contents);`
3. Save back to file using the new data in `$contents`

***Create a backup first or write it to a new tmp file!***

Edit: See above. The only change was in the regexp. `(?:end` was changed to `(?:EndTimecode`

Edit2: I hope they all look the same. Try this

Regexp: `/<p start="[0-9]{2}:([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})" EndTimecode="[0-9]{2}:([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})"\sTitle='(.+?)'/>/`

Replace String: `<p begin="$1:$2.$3" end="$4:$5.$6">$7</p>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please look at my updated question? I have updated it as I realize that using regular expressions find and replace is the best solution in Notepad++, but I can't figure out how to do the whole thing in one line?
Thank you!!!!

Comment: See my edit for how to replace EndTimecode with end. Edit: Er, I see there are other changes to be made as well.

Comment: See my last edit, that should do. If you want it in notepad++, just remove the leading and ending `/`

Comment: Hey I have managed to figure out how to use the code you gave me to do the replace I am almost finished, but the last part I cant figure out. How to replace Title='Some text.'/> with Some text</p>, I can do everything else,could you help me figure the last part out please? Thank you!

Comment: Its OK I see you already told me how I just overlooked it! Thank you so much for saving me the amount of time it would taken to do this myself!!

I appreciate it!!!!